# google maps nongeographical space

Tags: google-maps, space

I’m wondering if one of you can point me to a Google Maps API V3 code example which solves the following problem:

I have a data set with two-dimensional point data which is NOT georeferenced; i.e., the data do NOT refer to locations on the surface of the earth. In my case the data are for documents located in an artificial/synthetic, two-dimensional ‘information’ space.

For the moment I am successful in displaying and interacting with these points in the Google Maps API, mapping all points as long/lat coordinates centered on the long/lat coordinate 0:0; i.e., somewhere in the Atlantic Ocean off of the West coast of Africa :-)

Although I can get away with this for experimental purposes (the ocean around 0:0 is pretty much empty, so it does not interfere with my visualization), I’d like to adopt a new, abstract coordinate space; essentially replacing Google’s ROAD/TERRAIN/etc. maptype with my own (empty) one.

From what I have googled, this can indeed be done and I have seen some impressive DNA/genomics work in which this has in fact been done.  But rather than hacking those complex apps, I’d like to see a very simple, base code example where someone plots some arbitrary points in an arbitrary space using the Google API.

Can one of you point me to such an example?

Answer (score 0):

All,

I appears that the answer was in front of me all along (it usually is... sigh).
It seems that developers.google.com gives a nice example at 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes.

The code for the example itself is at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base

Seems like this is basic enough for me to start working from.